# 'good kvitel' and 'gmar tov'

Tags: yom-kippur, sukkot

Why do people say (I have no source that they do, but they do...) 'good kvitel' and 'gmar tov' after yom Kippur?

Good kvitel - not really sure what that is about at all.

Gmar tov - as far as I can tell, it is all over at the end of yom Kippur..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Kabbalistic teachings, the final verdicts are given on Hoshana Rabba. Therefore, it is customary to still wish one another "a gutten kvittel" (Yiddish for "פתק טוב/פתקא טבא") until then. This thought originates from the Zohar ([parshat Tzav, 31b](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%92_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%91)):

> ביומא שביעאה דחג, הוא סיומא דדינא 
>   דעלמא, ופתקין נפקין מבי מלכא

Trans.:

> On the seventh day of the holiday (Sukkot) is the end of the world's judgment and slips are dispensed from the King's court.

(Note: Later Kabbalists, primarily, Hassidic masters, extended this idea of "cut off time" to the last day of Hanukkah (designated, "Zot Hanukkah"), with the explanation that "although on RH decrees are written, on YK they are signed and on HR they are handed out, they are not executed until ZH".)

Comment: It is a bit odd that it is so widespread if  it is kabbalistic, but thanks

Comment: @MosheSteinberg - Not so odd. There are many widespread things that are al-pi kabbalah, such as keeping the kesher yud on the tefillin shel yad touching the bayis, wrapping the shel yad seven times around the arm, etc. Remember that Hasidim are not the only Ashkenazim who are kabbalists. The Vilna Gaon (an opposer to the Hasidic Movement and possibly the biggest name in Litvish history) was a kabbalist.